# Changing the default master page applied when creating a new page

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I have an InDesign document with two different page layouts, and two different master pages for each layout.

When I click "Create new page" in the Pages Panel, it defaults to applying the "B" Master to the new page. I would like it to default to apply the "A" Master to the new page when I click on the "Create new page" button.

I'm able to change what Master page is used after I create the page but this bogs down my work flow as I'm mostly using the "A" Master page, and the "B" master page is rarely used.

I feel like this should be an obvious option/setting but I can't find it for the life of me. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, InDesign applies to your new page whichever master is applied to the *currently selected page* in the page palette. If your current page has master B, it inserts a new page with master B. Is your current page A, you get a new page with master A.

Comment: Oh, and: welcome to GD.SE, David! Thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for clearing up the logic behind it. This definitely answers my question. I must have been getting unlucky and for some reason have a page with the "B" master applied to it selected when creating new pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe isn't completely accurate.

InDesign applies to your new page whichever master is applied to the *currently selected page* in the page palette. If your current page has master B, it inserts a new page with master B. Is your current page A, you get a new page with master A.

So you could force a certain master on your new page by selecting a page with the matching master. An alternative would be to use the Page panel's options and choose <kbd>Insert Pages...</kbd> there. In the dialogue that pops up, you can choose what master to apply to your new pages, as well as where they should be inserted.